# Page numbers in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, page-numbering

I'm building a report which is about 50 pages when rendered. it is like a power point presentation. The only issue is I  want to display page numbers from second page starting from '1'. When I use the global page number function in the footer it shows the page no. on the first page also. It'd be a great help if anybody can help me with  work around..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should place a textbox to write the page number only (label "Page:, for example, should be in a separate textbox) and use an expression, something like this:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1, "", cStr(Globals!PageNumber-1))
```